# Setting a remote git repository on AWS and pushing from Windows

Tags: git, amazon-ec2, ssh, putty

I am trying to create a remote repository on my Ubuntu Instance on AWS and then push from my local repository on Windows. I followed the tutorial [here](https://gist.github.com/matthewoden/b29353e266c554e04be8ea2058bcc2a0).

I followed these exact steps:

1. I created an Ubuntu instance on AWS.
2. I did `ssh-add path/to/myKP.pem`.
   It gave me an error `Could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent`.
3. Then I ran this `eval $(ssh-agent)`  and did step 2 again. Now it said **Identity added**.
4. I generated a .ppk file with **myKP.pem** and then used it to ssh into my ubuntu instance with Putty.
5. Ran these commands: `apt-get update` and `apt-get install git-core`.
6. `mkdir repo.git` and `cd repo.git` and `git init --bare`
7. Then from my local directory I ran `git init` and `git add .` and `git commit -m "Init commit"`
8. `git remote add origin ubuntu@publicIP:/repo.git`
9. `git config --global remote.origin.receivepack "git receive-pack"`.
10. `git push origin master`.

Then I got this error:

```
fatal: 'ubuntu@publicIP/repo.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Can someone give tell me the steps I should follow to create an empty git repository on my Ubuntu instance and then push from my local repository.

**NOTE** that I am using Windows.

**Edit:** Do I need to store my *.pem* file on my Ubuntu instance too?

I am sorry if it's really easy for some people, but I am new to SSH and AWS.

Answer (score 4):

The instructions seems correct. The below sequence of steps should work.

**EC2 instance**

```
Install git if not available via apt-get (Ubuntu) or yum install (CentOS)
$ mkdir test-repo.git
$ cd test-repo.git
$ git init --bare
```

**Local machine ssh-add**

This is the .pem file that was specified when setting up the EC2 instance. It does not need to be on the EC2 instance.

```
ssh-add path/to/local/ec2.pem
```

For Windows, you can download [GitHub Desktop For Windows](https://desktop.github.com/). Once you have installed it, `ssh-add` should be available. Follow these [steps](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent) to add the `ec2.pem` file (private key) to the `ssh auth agent` (**Windows tab - Section: Adding your SSH key to the ssh-agent**)

**Local machine push to repository**

```
mkdir test-repo
cd test-repo
git init
echo "This is a test repo" > README.md
git add README.md 
git commit -m "Added readme file"
git remote add origin ec2-user@aws-host-name-or-ip-here:/path/to/test-repo.git
git remote -v #for-verification
git config --global remote.origin.receivepack "git receive-pack"
git push origin master
```

Comment: When I do `ssh-add path/to/local/ec2.pem`. It says could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

Comment: Run this before executing ssh-add: eval $(ssh-agent -s)

Comment: It said Identity added after running that command but I am getting the same error. `Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.`

Comment: Does the output of git remote -v look correct? And the correct .pem was used corresponding to the EC2 instance? All other steps ran fine without errors?

Comment: Yes it did looked correct. And I am using the correct .pem file. I have terminated and created my instance a lot of times and done all the steps again. Still no luck. I wish there was an easy way to do this.

Comment: I have edited and added more details in the question. Can you see it now please?

Comment: The path in step 8 of your updated post does not seem correct. Run command ‘pwd’ on the instance dir where repo.git exists and use that path.

Comment: Nope didn't work. The path when I did pwd `/home/ubuntu/repo.git` and I did this `git remote add origin ubuntu@publicIP:/home/ubuntu/repo.git`

Comment: **git remote -v** returns me `origin  ubuntu@publicIP:/home/ubuntu/repo.git (fetch)` and 
`origin  ubuntu@publicIP:/home/ubuntu/repo.git (push)`

Comment: Ok. Can you try running through my list of commands once again please? Now that you have `ssh-add working`, it will be useful to see if you can run through them in the exact sequence, and then check the push once again.

Comment: No I already did that a couple of times after `ssh-add` command. Didn't work. Is it something to do with my security group? Cause I am using **ssh** and **http** while launching my Instance. Do I need anything else?

Comment: Regarding security group: Try editing the instance's security group to allow **All traffic**, but just limit the **Source** to your public IP address. And then try the `push` once more.

Comment: Still no luck. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

SSH has 2 ways to log in: either with username/password combo, or with a private/public key combo. The good thing about public/private keys is that after you set it up, you don't have to type the username/password each time for you git commands (when you do git push/pull to an SSH remote server).

If you use PuTTY, it has a tool puttygen (c:\Program Files\PuTTY\puttygen.exe) that will help you to generate the keys on your Windows machine. It has 2 buttons: "Save public key" is to save just your public key into a file like "DragonBorn.pem". "Save private key" is to save both public and private key in one file like "DragonBorn.ppk".

So normally "pem" contains just the public key, and you only need that key to be copied to the server (the server should not have access to your private key). If you add your public key to the list of trusted keys on the server (`authorized_keys`), the server will let you in without a password.

There are tools to help you with copying your key to the server, but it is actually easy to do it by hand:

1. inside puttygen.exe there a text field on top that says "Public key for pasting...", copy that.
2. login to your SSH server with PuTTY using your username/password
3. open the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` in the SSH terminal. Usually you can use vim for that, type command: `vi ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
4. paste your public key from puttygen into the text editor in the SSH terminal. If using vim you first press "i" (this starts editing in vi), and then do right mouse click to paste (that's a PuTTY's own shortcut).
5. save the file and quit. If using vim press "escape" (to stop editing) and then hold "shift" and press "z" 2 times (like "shift-z-z").

Now the server is set up.

It is not the end :))
To set up the client, you need to tell PuTTY to use your private key "DragonBorn.ppk" to log in.
This is done inside PuTTY configuration in Connection - SSH - Auth category on the left, and on the right it will have "Private key file for authentication" - this is where you specify your ppk.

It is not quite intuitive, but in PuTTY you have to first select your session from the list of "Saved Sessions", click "Load", then you modify the settings (for example specify "ppk"), and then go back to "Session" and press "Save" button. This will save it for the future.

Comment: You mean the public key that I downloaded from Amazon or Generate a new key and then copy from "Public key for pasting"?

Comment: Yes, I mean that you can generate a new key that belongs to you and use it for git+ssh+putty. I assume that you can log in to your Ubuntu AWS intance using login/password to install that public key to authorized_keys.

Comment: No I used my .ppk file to login to my Ubuntu instance with putty. I have edited and added more details in the question. Can you see it now please?

Comment: Perfect, then you don't need my steps. You're almost there. You have created the repo locally, and try to push it to remote. I would to it otherwise: log in with SSH to the remote machine, create a repo there ( like `mkdir repo.git && cd repo.git && git init --bare`, can do with or without `--bare` ), and then locally do `git clone ubuntu@publicIP:repo.git`, after that you should be able to commit and push. Your problem now is that when you "push" the repo will not magically appear on remote, you have to create it first, and then "push" will put stuff into existing repo.

Comment: P.S. No, you don't need .pem on Ubuntu.

Comment: But I have already created my repo on remote. Check step 6 in my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170471/discussion-between-battlmonstr-and-dragonborn).